# Findpeaks coordinates not matching X axis coordinates (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, figure, smoothing

I have a piece of code that is not performing as intended (at least in my view) and was hoping if someone could help clarify this issue.

The code plots a histogram of my data and the applies a ksdensity function to smooth the data, finally it runs a findpeaks function to return the max values plotted. However the coordinates for the horizontal axis do not correspond to the graphical representation of the plotted data.

```
MB(A); %array with the data to be plotted
figure;
histogram(MB(A),25)

[f,xi] = ksdensity(MB(A), 'Bandwidth',10);
figure;
plot(xi,f);
[peaks,loc] = findpeaks(f)
```

the result from this piece of code are  that:

**peaks =
    0.0232       0.0017

loc =
    27      76**

however when looking at the graphical representation the coordinates of the peaks (for the horizontal axis) are very different from these values

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea9Fd.jpg)
[smoothed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApuQW.jpg)

I originally thought that might be a problem of over or under fitting but after playing around with the values a little bit the issue remained. Am I just missing some basic concept? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[loc]** location is the **index** of the point, so you would get the graphical x by:

```
xi(loc)
```

see matlab help for info on the returned variables:

```
[PKS,LOCS]= findpeaks(Y) also returns the indices LOCS at which the
    peaks occur.
```